# How to access local Storage data inside window-all-closed event

Tags: electron, local-storage

I am quite new to Electron and have been trying out electron-react-boilerplate for my application. I do have a requirement where I have to send an API request with the data that is saved in the local storage, in case the electron application is closed by clicking the window close button. I tried adding the code for the below events.

```js
app.on('ready', createWindow);

const createWindow = async () => {

     mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
     show: false,
     webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
        }
     });

     mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
       alert('123');
       const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
       // ...Service call
    });

};

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    // ...Service call
});
```

When I am closing the application, I get the below two errors:

```
Reference Error: alert is not defined
```

```
Reference Error: localStorage is not defined
```

Could someone please help me and let me know what is the mistake am making in the above.

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't do so and wouldn't be able to in closer time according to the [issue 9110](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9110).  But you can send localStorage to the main script before window is closed. To do so:

1. Add new script on preload using window options:

   ```js
   const win = new BrowserWindow({
      webPreferences: {
          preload: './local-storage-sync.js',
      },
   })

   win.webContents.on('ipc-message-sync', (e, channel, ...args) => {
     if (channel === 'local-storage') {
        // Do something with local storage.
     }
   })
   ```
2. Create `local-storage-sync.js`:

   ```js
   const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');
   window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
      ipcRenderer.sendSync('local-storage', JSON.stringify(localStorage))
   });
   ```

This is how you can retrieve origin's localStorage into main process. But note that this method could be expensive with intensive page loading.